# Como enviar formulários automaticamente sem usar submit e sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, banco-de-dados

Olá,

Sou um programador relativamente novo em php e estou desenvolvendo um site. É um site onde há uma lista de empresas. E eu queria implementar nele, filtros de pesquisa, o primeiro deles sendo um select "Selecione sua cidade":

```
<form method="post" action="lista.php" id="Cidade" name="Cidade">
   <label for="cCidade">Selecione sua Cidade</label>
   <select id="cCidade" name="tCidade">
      <option>Selecione a Cidade</option>
      <option value="Farroupilha">Farroupilha</option>
      <option value="Caxias do Sul"default>Caxias do Sul</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Eu quero que quando o usuário utilizar o `select`, os resultados são enviados para um `iframe` na tela (o "lista.php"), que é a listagem das empresas como falei anteriormente. Porém eu quero que esse envio, não atualize a página e nem precise de um botão para ser enviado, ou seja, sempre que o usuário usar outra option do select, a pesquisa mude totalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite Nicolas,

Para conseguir isso você deve ter algum conhecimento em `AJAX` e `JavaScript`. Vou tentar explicar como funcionaria isso.

Primeiro, você deve saber quando que o `select` foi atualizado. Para identificar isso, você precisa ouvir um evento da tag `select` que é disparado cada vez que o `select` muda de `option`. Você pode atingir esse objetivo com o seguinte trecho:

```
var select = document.getElementById("cCidade");
    select.addEventListener("change", function(e){
        //O código aqui dentro será executado toda vez que usuário trocar o select
    });
```

Em seguida, é necessário que você envie uma requisição para o servidor de forma assíncrona toda vez que o usuário trocar a cidade. Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var select = document.getElementById("cCidade");
    var xhttp;
    select.addEventListener("change", function(e){
        xhttp =  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                //aqui dentro você manipula os dados das empresas retornados pelo servidor
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "lista.php?cidade" + select.value, true);
        xhttp.send();
    });
```

*Repare que você está passando um **parameter** chamado **cidade** e pegando dinamicamente o valor de `select.value`*. Você pode notar isso na linha: **`xhttp.open("GET", "lista.php?cidade" + select.value, true);`**

Pronto. Dessa forma você não está utilizando nenhum botão e nem atualizando a página para ter seus dados retornados de acordo com um query dinamica enviada pela página.

Se você está em dúvida o que está sendo feito nesse código, sugiro que busque na web sobre os seguintes tópicos.

- Como fazer uma requisição AJAX para back-end PHP
- O que é uma função de callback
- O que XMLHttpRequest
- Como ouvir eventos em `JavaScript`

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Olá Andrew! Muito obrigado por ter ajudado! Só uma dúvida, se eu quiser criar uma váriavel com esse resultado eu uso qual sintaxe? E se for pro mesmo documento?

Comment: Se o retorno do seu back-end for apenas um texto, você irá utilizar o atributo `responseText` da variável  xhttp. Se por um acaso, você retorna uma lista de empresas em formato JSON, por exemplo, você pode fazer o seguinte: `var myjson = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);`.
Pronto, sua variável `myjson` vai ser um objeto `JavaScript` manipulável, contendo todos os dados retornados do PHP. Basta você ir montar sua página.

Comment: Ahh sim, isso também é uma dúvida, mas e se eu quiser criar uma váriavel pra receber qual é a cidade atual selecionada pelo usuário?

Comment: Simples. A cidade atual está armazenado em `select.value`. Se você quer salvar isso numa variável, basta fazer `var atual = select.value;`

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui e quando criar essa variável e tento exibir ela na tela, ela aparece como vazia, porque?